# I am failing to call a method in Java and have been unable to find a solution. Currently getting "cannot resolve symbol findfutureAge". How can I fix?

Tags: java, methods, symbols

I'm a student and quite new to Java, I am trying to write a program to calculate someone's age given a hypothetical future year. I am learning methods and how to call from them so that is required for this program, but for some reason I can't get this to work. I feel like I must be close but am missing something obvious. I've tried a few different ways to make this work but have had no success. Currently I am getting a "cannot resolve symbol findfutureAge"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a future year: ");
        int futureYear = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your age would be " + findfutureAge);
    }

    public static int findFutureAge(int age, int futureYear) {
        return futureYear - 2021 + age;
    }
}
```

Comment: `findFutureAge` (notice the capitalization, with `Future` starting with a big `F`, java is case-sensitive) is a method. You need to call it and pass it parameters (likely as `findFutureAge(age, futureYear)`).

Comment: Also, it's 2023, not 2021.

Comment: You should also understand that this is not a good way to check for ages. Besides the fact that the current year shouldn't be hardcoded, an age is checked by birthdate, not just per year. No one has the same age an entire year. So, depending on when in the year you execute your code, your result might be wrong

Comment: The way age is calculated and the year 2021 are parameters of the practice problem we were given, I assume 2021 was current when this was first assigned and the goal of the practice was method call, so I think they probably wanted to make the math as simple as possible not to add complexity there.

Comment: System.out.println("Your age would be " + findFutureAge(age, futureYear)); This worked, thank you. Now that I'm looking at this solution, I can see why it would be set to work this way although it's not intuitive to me having not run into this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating `findfutureAge` as a variable, but there isn't such variable.
There is a method, `findFutureAge` (case sensitive), but you'll need to add the parameters in order to actually call it.

Change the next line:

```
System.out.println("Your age would be " + findfutureAge);
```

to:

```
System.out.println("Your age would be " + findFutureAge(age, futureYear));
```